# Can I install and run a chromium without any GUI on Ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, chromium

I have a naked Ubuntu-16.4-machine with no GUI, only the console. Can I somehow install and run chromium on this? or do I have to install a GUI to use a browser?

how would I do this?

Comment: You probably want this: https://lynx.browser.org/ instead.

Comment: Could you please give us a little bit more information what you want to achieve? Do you need to browse websites on the console? Or do you want to automate website testing on a headless machine?

Comment: @all . thanks for lynx.. it is exactly what I needed !! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't use chromium directly, but you can use selenium with python and use chromium headless. here is a sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
opts.add_argument("--headless")
opts.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

you can also capture screenshots to check the webpage:

```
enter driver.get_screenshot_as_file("capture.png")
```